# Running script from Heroku CLI

Tags: javascript, heroku, sequelize.js, yargs, heroku-cli

I have a script that I want to run through the Heroku CLI. It's just a simple script to create a user in a postgressql database with Sequelize.
This is the script:

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sqlizr = require('sqlizr');
require('dotenv').load();


// Check params
if (!argv.username) { throw new Error('username is required!'); }
if (!argv.password) { throw new Error('password is required!'); }
if (!argv.clientId) { throw new Error('client id is required!'); }

// Init db connection
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASS,
  {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: false
  }
)

var client_id = argv.clientId;
if(argv.clientId === -1){
  client_id = 0;
}

console.log(sequelize)

sqlizr(sequelize, 'api/models/**/*.js');

// Check if user exists
console.log('Check is user exists...');
sequelize.models.USERS.count({
  where: {
    USERNAME: argv.username
  }
})
  .then(result => {
    if (result > 0) {
      console.error('user already exists!');
      process.exit(1);
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Creating user...');
    sequelize.models.USERS.create({
      USERNAME: argv.username,
      PASSWORD: argv.password,
      CLNT_ID: client_id,
      EMAIL: 'email@email.com',
      PHONE: '123456789'
    })
     .then(result => {
       console.log('User created successfully!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Could not create user!', error);
      })
      .finally(result => {
        process.exit(1);
      });
  });
```

Everything goes well if I execute this command locally:

```
 node bin/createUser.js --username admin --password admin --clientId -1
```

But If i try to run this through the Heroku CLI like this:

```
heroku run bin/createUser.js --username admin --password admin --clientId -1
```

I get this in the terminal:

```
bin/createUser.js: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bin/createUser.js: line 4: `const yargs = require('yargs');'
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Hopefully someone can help me and explain why this is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify `node` in the command, so I suspect that Heroku is trying to run `createUser.js` as if it were a shell script.

You may need to install a node.js buildpack to be able to run the program on Heroku, but try:

```
heroku run node bin/createUser.js --username admin --password admin --clientId -1
```